# Pyinstaller - “Fatal error ! Failed to execute script” when converting script to exe

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I have a GUI built with tkinter, this makes webscraping by reading links from an excel file and then stores all the results in excel files. Also, it has buttons that allows plot de data from excel files doing some easy filters. I have it built correctly in Pycharm. Now, what I need is to built an exe file and for this I'm using pyinstaller with this code `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed main.py`. The problem is that it gives a fatal error and fail to execute the script.  I already tried to install all the packages in cmd in my enviroment, but the error persist.
Here I put my main.py (here the [link](https://github.com/FrancoRamos/graphics_rankings) to github where is functions.py and the input data):

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from functions import *
import os
import threading

excel_QS_resultados = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/Resultados_QS"
excel_ponderacion_name = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/Ponderación_Metologías"
def open_file():
    browse_text.set("Ejecutando...")
    file = askopenfile(parent = root, mode = "rb", title = "Elija un archivo", filetype = [("Excel file", "*.xlsx")])

    if file:
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/Tablas"):
            os.mkdir(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/Tablas")
        #print(os.getcwd())
        guardar_tablas(file.name[:-5], os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/Tablas",
                       excel_QS_resultados, root)
 
        browse_text.set("Cargar tablas de las webs de rankings")

def to_plot(kind, latam = False):
    file = askopenfile(parent=root, mode="rb", title="Elija un archivo", filetype=[("Excel file", "*.xlsx")])
    if file:
        if "QS" in os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(file.name[:-5])):
            ranking_name = "QS"
            subjects_QS = {0: os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(file.name[:-5]))[3:]}
            subjects_THE = {}
        else:
            ranking_name = "THE"
            subjects_THE = {0: os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(file.name[:-5]))[4:]}
            subjects_QS = {}

        df_subject = pd.read_excel(file.name)
        if ranking_name == "QS":
            list_years, list_years_2 = Get_If_UniRanked(df_subject, ranking_name, excel_QS_resultados, subjects_QS,
                                                        0)  # También imprime años rankeados

            list_years_rank = ["La PUCP fue rankeada en el año " + str(year) for year in list_years]
            list_years_result = ["Se tienen los resultados de la PUCP en el año " + str(year) for year in list_years_2]

            if list_years_rank == []:
                list_years_rank.append("La PUCP no fue rankeada en ninguno de los años")

            if list_years_result == []:
                list_years_result.append("No se tienen resultados de la PUCP en ninguno de los años")

            top = Toplevel(root)
            canvas2 = Canvas(top, width=600, height=300)
            canvas2.pack()

            header = Frame(canvas2, width=500, height=200, bg =  "#14a4d6")
            header.grid(columnspan=5, rowspan=2, row=0)

            header1 = Frame(canvas2, width=500, height=15, bg =  "#14a4d6")
            header1.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=1, row=1)

            main_content = Frame(canvas2, width=500, height=100, bg="#14a4d6")
            main_content.grid(columnspan=5, row=2)

            display_text_box("\n".join(map(str, list_years_rank + list_years_result)), 0, 1, canvas2)

            instructions = Label(header1, text="Seleccione el año ",font="Raleway")
            instructions.grid(column=1, row=2)

            for i in range(len(list_years)):
                button = Button(main_content, text=list_years[i], font=("shanti", 10), height = 1, width = 6)
                button.grid(column=i, row=1, padx = 15, pady = 15)

        else:
            list_years = Get_If_UniRanked(df_subject, ranking_name, excel_QS_resultados, subjects_THE, 0)

            list_years_rank = ["La PUCP fue rankeada en el año " + str(year) for year in list_years]

            if list_years_rank == []:
                list_years_rank.append("La PUCP no fue rankeada en ninguno de los años")

            top = Toplevel(root)
            canvas2 = Canvas(top, width=600, height=300)
            canvas2.pack()

            header = Frame(canvas2, width=500, height=200, bg="#14a4d6")
            header.grid(columnspan=5, rowspan=2, row=0)

            header1 = Frame(canvas2, width=500, height=15, bg="#14a4d6")
            header1.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=1, row=1)

            main_content = Frame(canvas2, width=500, height=100, bg="#14a4d6")
            main_content.grid(columnspan=5, row=2)

            display_text_box("\n".join(map(str, list_years_rank )), 0, 1, canvas2)

            instructions = Label(header1, text="Seleccione el año ", font="Raleway")
            instructions.grid(column=1, row=2)

    if kind  ==3:
        list_years = list_years_2[::-1]
    for i in range(len(list_years)):
        button = Button(main_content, text=list_years[i], font=("shanti", 10), height=1, width=6,
                        command =lambda i=i: plot(file, ranking_name, subjects_THE, subjects_QS, str(list_years[i]), kind, latam))
        button.grid(column=i, row=1, padx=15, pady=15)

def plot(file, ranking_name, subjects_THE, subjects_QS, year, kind, latam):
    df_subject = pd.read_excel(file.name)
    df_with_method = apply_methodology_continent(df_subject, excel_ponderacion_name, ranking_name, 0,
                                                 subjects_THE, subjects_QS).copy()
    time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    if ranking_name == "QS":
        df_with_method.to_excel(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/" + ranking_name + " " + subjects_QS[0] + " " + time + ".xlsx",
                                index=False)
    elif ranking_name == "THE":
        df_with_method.to_excel(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/" +  ranking_name + " " + subjects_THE[0] + " " + time + ".xlsx",
                                index=False)
    else:
        pass  # datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    if kind == 1:
        df_6Higher_Uni = Get_6Higher_Uni(df_with_method, int(year), ranking_name, latam)
        if df_6Higher_Uni is not None:
            Plot_6Higher_Uni(df_6Higher_Uni, ranking_name, latam)
            Plot_6HigherUni_Contribution(df_6Higher_Uni, excel_ponderacion_name, subjects_QS,
                                         subjects_THE, 0, ranking_name, latam)
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia",
                                   "Existen datos incompletos en el mismo rango de puestos que la PUCP. Analice un año anterior.")
    elif kind == 2:
        df_6Bottom_Uni = Get_6Bottom_Uni(df_with_method, int(year), ranking_name, latam)
        if df_6Bottom_Uni is not None:
            Plot_6Higher_Uni(df_6Bottom_Uni, ranking_name, latam)
            Plot_6HigherUni_Contribution(df_6Bottom_Uni, excel_ponderacion_name, subjects_QS,
                                         subjects_THE, 0, ranking_name, latam)
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia",
                                   "Existen datos incompletos en el mismo rango de puestos que la PUCP. Analice un año anterior.")
    else:
        df_6Bottom_Uni = Get_6Bottom_Uni_QS_Result(df_with_method, int(year), excel_ponderacion_name,
                                                   excel_QS_resultados, 0, subjects_QS, latam)
        if df_6Bottom_Uni is not None:
            Plot_6Higher_Uni(df_6Bottom_Uni, ranking_name, latam)
            Plot_6HigherUni_Contribution(df_6Bottom_Uni, excel_ponderacion_name, subjects_QS,
                                         subjects_THE, 0, ranking_name, latam)
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia",
                                   "Existen datos incompletos en el mismo rango de puestos que la PUCP. Analice un año anterior.")

root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/Franco/PycharmProjects/THE_QS/icon.ico")
root.title("Generador de gráficos- Rankings THE y QS by Subject")

header = Frame(root, width=800, height=150)
header.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=2, row=0)

main_content = Frame(root, width=800, height=150, bg="#14a4d6")
main_content.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=4, row=4)

btn_options = ["R - Siguientes 6 Univ. Rankeadas Global",
                    "R - Siguientes 6 Univ. Rankeadas LATAM",
                    "NR/R - Últimas 6 Universidades Rankeadas Global",
                    "NR/R - Últimas 6 Universidades Rankeadas LATAM",
                    "NR - QS Últimas Universidades Rankeadas Global",
                    "NR - QS Últimas Universidades Rankeadas LATAM"]


next6Global_btn = Button(root, text = btn_options[0], font=("shanti", 10), height = 1, width = 40, command = lambda: to_plot(kind = 1))
next6Latam_btn = Button(root, text = btn_options[1], font=("shanti", 10), height = 1, width = 40, command = lambda: to_plot(kind = 1, latam=True))
last6Global_btn = Button(root, text = btn_options[2], font=("shanti", 10), height = 1, width = 40, command = lambda: to_plot(kind = 2))
last6Latam_btn = Button(root, text = btn_options[3], font=("shanti", 10), height = 1, width = 40, command = lambda: to_plot(kind = 2, latam=True))
QSlast6Global_btn = Button(root, text = btn_options[4], font=("shanti", 10), height = 1, width = 40, command = lambda: to_plot(kind = 3))
QSlast6Latam_btn = Button(root, text = btn_options[5], font=("shanti", 10), height = 1, width = 40, command = lambda: to_plot(kind = 3, latam=True))

next6Global_btn.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
next6Latam_btn.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
last6Global_btn.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
last6Latam_btn.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
QSlast6Global_btn.grid(row = 6, column = 1)
QSlast6Latam_btn.grid(row = 6, column = 2)

# logo
display_logo("C:/Users/Franco/PycharmProjects/THE_QS/pucp-logo.png", 0, 1)

# instructions
instructions = Label(root, text="Seleccione el archivo excel con los enlaces de los rankings by subject", font="Raleway")
instructions.grid(columnspan=4, rowspan= 3, column=1, row=1)


# browse
browse_text = StringVar()
browse_text.set("Cargar tablas de las webs de rankings")
browse_btn = Button(root, textvariable = browse_text, font="Raleway", bg="#14a4d6",
                       command = lambda: threading.Thread(target=open_file).start(), fg="white", height=2, width=35)

browse_btn.grid(columnspan = 3, column=1, row=2)


root.mainloop()
```

I really appreciate some help on this because I've already tried some time and don't get it works.

---

**UPDATE**

After some months left this project without finished, I wanted to prove some of the new suggestion from yours I got.
I tried with @Blueman7 suggestion about missing `icon=part` and the commands I used in cmd are the following (In case I made an error in execution, because it still doesn't work but there's some improvement):

- cd project_path
- conda activate environment_name
- pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon=icon.ico main.py

After this commands are executed I got a main.exe with my icon.ico. When I try to run this .exe, it opens a black window and keeps like that for around 1 minute when it gives the error in this image which is related pyzmq package.

[image]

I tried copy this folder pyzmq.libs to my current project path and run the command `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon=icon.ico --add-data "./pyzmq.libs;." main.py` in cmd. Also, I tried importing pyzmq to my conda environment, nut it neither works so far.
Thanks a lot for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a screenshot of what error you have obtained is always helpful to understand your problem.

But from information you have given ,I think your problem is with the command your are using and it should be ,

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py
```

for detailed information on how to create executable using pyinstaller have a look at this -> https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

if this didn't works then try using [py2exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/)

and have a look at this,

https://stackabuse.com/creating-executable-files-from-python-scripts-with-py2exe

Comment: can you provide the error you are getting!!

Comment: try using py2exe or other such packages if pyinstaller does not works.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`pyinstaller onefile -w main.py`

Is this working?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is just:

`pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

without -windowed or -w

Answer (score 0):

In your code you forgot to mention the icon=part.

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=yourico.ico main.py
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me, but now it brought me a new error (I already updated about this in my post.)